# how can i put different colors in ListView

Tags: android, row, android-arrayadapter

i want to get the different colors in each row of the list view

but current only one color is shown

so how can i do this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String(this,R.layout.latesthappenings,R.id.LH_Titles,titles);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

i want to different color in each row

please tell how can i do

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `anonymous ArrayAdapter` you have to write code inside `getView()`

### Sudo code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
           this,R.layout.main,R.id.textview1,titles){

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if(position ==condition){
convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);}
else if(second condition){convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.something else);}

    return view;};
   };
```

ANother approach is

Why donot you do for Customized ListView? You can manage view as per your requirement there.

Have a [Custom ArrayAdapter](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html)

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Set all the different colors (that you want in your list) codes in an array and fetch color code from that array for each row position and use **setBackgroundColor()** method to set that background color to the list row.

Try this.